# Force Login page on token expiry

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-identity-2

I am attempting to force Identity Server 4 (v 2.1.1) with ASP.Net Identity to redirect to the Login page after a certain period. I have set every token lifetime/timeout I can to 1 minute and even accounting for a 5 minute skew Identity Server keeps re-authenticating the user automatically (i.e. no login page required).

Here is the pertinent code

IdentityServer Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                                   {
                                       options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                                       options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = false;
                                   })
        .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
        .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.GetClients())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication();
```

Config.GetGlients():

```
// WebForms Client
new Client
{
    ...
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 60,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 60,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 60,
    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 60
},
```

Web-Forms Client Middleware Layer:

```
public void AuthSetup(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Use Cookies to Store JWT Token for Web Browsers
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        SlidingExpiration = true
    });

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    // Authenticate to Auth Server
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "oidc",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        Authority = "http://localhost:5002/",
        ClientId = "client",
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:8888/",
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:8888/",
        ResponseType = "code id_token token",
        Scope = "openid profile AuthApi",
        UseTokenLifetime = false,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
            {
                var claimsToExclude = new[] { "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash", "c_hash", "idp", "amr" };

                var claimsToKeep = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Where(x => false == claimsToExclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                claimsToKeep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                {
                    // Add access_token so we don't need to request it when calling APIs
                    claimsToKeep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "connect/userinfo").ToString());
                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                    var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims
                        .Where(x => x.Type != "sub") // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token
                        .Select(x => new Claim(x.Type, x.Value));
                    claimsToKeep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                }

                var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role");
                ci.AddClaims(claimsToKeep);

                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
            },
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });

    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
}
```

What other setting(s) am I missing to force the server to require the user to login after the token expiration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity Server creates it's own authentication cookie "idsrv" that by default has a [lifetime of 10 hours](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Constants.cs#L20). For 10 hours it will reauthenticate you automatically. To change this default you can change the `CookieLifetime` property when configuring Identity Server e.g.

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            })
        .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
        .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.GetClients())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication();
```

Also, in your WebForms client `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` you may want to set the `UseTokenLifetime` property to `true`.

Comment: I made both changes as well as setting CookieSlidingExpiration = false and it is still creating a new token without forcing re-login.

Comment: This works if you are NOT using ASP.Net Identity with version 2.1.1 of IdentityServer4. I'm marking this the answer for future users since it is AN answer. Thanks Gavin!

Comment: Gavin, is this the same as setting `AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc` when calling `SignInAsync` inside `ExternalLoginCallback`

Comment: @VictorioBerra. I'm not sure to be honest as I've not dug into using external providers too much. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationproperties.expiresutc?view=aspnetcore-2.0) indicates that it  _"Gets or sets the time at which the authentication ticket expires."_ so sounds plausible.

Comment: What is it about the combination of ASP.Net Identity 2.1.1 and IdentityServer4  that makes that this solution doesn't work? I'm running into the exact same issue and looking for a fix/workaround...

Comment: Same here. Using Identity with IdentityServer4 isn't reauthorizing

Comment: @GlennDOrr. _"Using Identity with IdentityServer4 **isn't** reauthorizing"_ ... the OP was about trying to make Identity Server **not** reauthorize but it is. Are you sure you're having the same problem?

Comment: @GavinSutherland No, you are correct. I'm having a different issue.